# Does one have to pay custom duties while bringing in a 'Fender Stratocaster American Standard' guitar from USA to India for himself?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, india, american-airlines, fragile-luggage

If I'm to buy a fender stratocaster guitar (price: $1,000) from USA and bring it to India box unopened (or opened- not a big deal), will I be asked to pay custom duties? If yes, how much?

The box weighs around 4- 8kgs I think. And can I hope to see my guitar in one piece when I get to India (meaning, will they let me have the guitar with me in the plane or if not, how safe will my guitar be in the luggage compartment)?

Comment: You probably need to split this into two questions, one about the customs/import duties, one about getting the guitar safely half way round the world with you

Comment: Will it arrive in one piece?   See here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5YGc4zOqozo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Declare the Guitar to Customs

When you arrive in India **you will have to declare the guitar to customs**. Since `1000.00 USD = 62315.00 INR` (today's rate from Google) you are in excess of the [`35000.00 INR` duty-free allowance accorded to Indian citizens](http://www.customsmumbaiairport.gov.in/forms/Content.aspx?LinkID=64) returning from a trip abroad longer than 3 days, **you will have to pay customs duty for this excess**. With today's rates your excess amount is `27315.00 INR`.

### Computing Custom Duty

[The Indian Central Board of Excise and Customs Travellers Guide (last updated 11 June 2014)](http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason11June2014.pdf) states that:

> The goods over and above the free allowances shall be chargeable to customs duty @ 35% + an education cess of 3% i.e. to say the effective rate is 36.05%.

For your guitar this becomes `36.05% of 27315.00 INR` which equates to a **total custom duty of `9847 INR`**.

Answer (score 2):

I have carried my 2 strats by unscrewing the neck from bodies and took in my suitcase 2 times. Wrapped it with bubble wrap and padded with cotton garments.

I would do this again anytime i have to carry my strats. I had sold off the cases as you can buy them india again